# Linq + nested GroupBy

Tags: mysql, linq, group-by

We are using mySQL with WCF Restful service, we want to fetch our database content PACKAGEID wise...as mentioned below:

```
    PackageId=2
    {
    StartRange = 1;
    EndRange = 100;
    IsDiscountAndChargeInPer = 1;
    Discount =10;
    ServiceCharge = 20;![enter image description here][1]
    },
    {
    StartRange =101;
    EndRange = 500;
    IsDiscountAndChargeInPer = 1;
    Discount =10;
    ServiceCharge = 20;
    }
    PackageId=3
    {
    StartRange = 1;
    EndRange = 100;
    IsDiscountAndChargeInPer = 1;
    Discount =10;
    ServiceCharge = 20;
    }
```

We have created a Result class to return result from out wcf service...for above service we have result class defined as below

```
[DataContract]
public class PackagePointRangeConfigurationResult : ResultBase
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<PackagePointRangeResult> Result;
}

public class PackagePointRangeResult
{
    public int PackageId { get; set; }

    public List<PointPlanInfo> Result { get; set; }
}
```

**For fetching record we use following linq query:**

```
    var result = (from planinfo in db.mst_pointplan_info
                                  join entityType in db.mst_entity_type
                                  on planinfo.entityId equals entityType.id
                                  where planinfo.entityId == entityId
                                  && planinfo.is_deleted != true
                                  && planinfo.system_id == systemId
                                  && entityType.enity_enum_id == entityId
                                  group planinfo by planinfo.package_id into gplan
                                  select new PackagePointRangeConfigurationResult
                                  {
                                  Result = (from planinfo in gplan
                                            select new PackagePointRangeResult
                                            {
                                                PackageId = planinfo.package_id,
                                                PointPlanInfo = (from pointPlanInfo in gplan
                                                select new PointPlanInfo
                                                {
                                                StartRange = planinfo.start_range,
                                                EndRange = planinfo.end_range,
                                        IsDiscountAndChargeInPer = planinfo.is_discount_and_charge_in_per,
                                                     Discount = planinfo.discount,
                                                     ServiceCharge = planinfo.servicecharge,
                                                     AtonMerchantShare =planinfo.aton_merchant_share,
                                                     CommunityShare = planinfo.community_share
                                                    }).ToList()
                                                }).ToList()
                                  }).FirstOrDefault();
```

But it gives me below error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[PointPlanInfo] ToList[PointPlanInfo](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[PointPlanInfo])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Error message is pretty self-descriptive. Query written in C# code should be converted into SQL code. EF knows how to convert join, where etc. But it does not know how to convert C# method `ToList()` into SQL code. Answer is always same - either move part which uses such methods to client, or remove such methods from query which will be sent to server. Make some search, you will find lot of similar questions

Comment: Not getting your question. You get error or want to other output from this code?

Comment: It is clearly mentioned that we get above mentioned error while executing that query and we need the output as mentioned above